# Array-variable interpolation in PHP

Tags: php

I am having trouble with the following:

file.php:

```
$row['name'] = "hello";

print("<img src=\"images/$row['name']\">");
```

Desired output:

```
     <img src="images/hello">
```

This generates a PHP error:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), 
    expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)
 or number (T_NUM_STRING) in 
/path/to/file/file.php on line NN
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Here's a link to the answer in the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly brackets ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)):

```
print("<img src='images{$row['name']}'>");
```

P.S. You can use single quotes for HTML attributes.